# Writing data-accessing code in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ejb, backend

I am a frontend developer who also does some backend work. I want to write an entire web app in php. Somehow, my backend team is hell-bent on using EJB, Struts etc...

Their reason for not using php is this -> "it is not advisable to write data-accessing code, that has queries etc.. in php. the backend is better written in ejb it is more secure" or something along those lines...

I mainly come from a .Net background - been into ASP.net for years. I am a novice when it comes to PHP and have no idea about EJB.

I am confused about what they are saying. The question of which to use for backend aside, is what they are saying true? Then how do websites that use PHP entirely, access data?

Can someone help me in understanding this whole backend confusion?

Oh yeah.. the database we use is MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I like to keep all my queries in a single logical place.  There's nothing wrong with PHP, it'll only get muddled up if they are bad developers.

As for security, it's up to you as the developer to ensure your code is robust and secure much the same as any other language.

Comment: so.. at a high level, php is just like any other server-side-scripting (language differences aside) language. Pretty much anything that can be done in other backend technologies, can be done in PHP. Did I get you right?

Answer (score 2):

Use another language to write backend because PHP is not secure enough? That's rubbish. Bad programmers produce bad code, it's not language to blame. If you write good secure code then it doesn't matter which language you choose.